# "System is undefined" JavaScript error when using click handler?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview with a button in one of the columns. I add columns to the gridview with the code behind. I used this line to attach my click event:

`cmd1.OnClientClick += new EventHandler(cmd1_Click);`

Now every time I click that button, it gives me a run time error and breaks at `System.EventHandler` of `<input type="submit" name="grvList$ctl02$ctl05" value="Add" onclick="System.EventHandler;" />`

Has anyone ran into this problem.

Comment: You're trying to use server side code to handle a client side event. `onclick` says to run this javascript stuff, not c# stuff

Comment: @scrappedcola most of the time yes, but this is dynamic HTML being generated by the code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user user1090190 wrote in a comment, `onclick` (generated from `OnClientClick`) is executed in the web-browser as JavaScript.

The `+=` in this case is calling `ToString()` on the new `EventHandler` object that is created which results in the string `"System.EventHandler"`. (The `+=` expression expands to `cmd1.OnClientClick = cmd1.OnClientClick + (new EventHandler(cmd1_Click));` and the implicit conversion happens because `OnClientClick` is typed as a string.)

It should likely be (note *no* `Client`):

```
cmd1.Click += new EventHandler(cmd1_Click)
```

Or, more simply (don't ask me why the auto-complete is always "wrapped"):

```
cmd1.Click += cmd1_Click;
```

Make sure this handler is setup *each* postback, as appropriate.

Happy coding.

Comment: you are correct, but there is no cmd1.OnClick it is there is cmd1.Click which appears to work.

Comment: @JoeTyman Thanks for the correction, updated. I am so lost without "intellisense" :(